# Angularjs and jQuery...function return jquery element

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have to use jQuery just because ng-grid needs it. But now I have some problem.
In directive, when I try to use angular's element, function returns me jQuery element. But if I remove jQuery from page, everything works just fine.

Is there any way to correct this?

```
app.directive('dynamic', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
                console.log(ele) //HERE
                ele.html(html);
                $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

When I have jQuery, element looks like this:

> [div, context: div, jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function, selector: "", toArray: function…]

Otherwise:

> [div, ready: function, toString: function, eq: function, push: function, sort: function…]

(I know it is not the full array, but you can see the difference).

- Example without jQuery: http://liveweave.com/05cWsP
- Example with jQuery: http://liveweave.com/w6QTpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has jqlite, which is a small subset of jQuery. It is used when jQuery isn't loaded on the page or is loaded after angular. Otherwise, angular will use jQuery instead of jqlite (but will still wrap it and add extra methods such as .scope() that jqlite has).

See documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

So to answer your question, this behavior makes sense.

Comment: Ok I get it, but my problem here is unsuccessful compiling, when I have whole jQuery on page -> $compile(ele.contents())(scope);

Comment: And it happens only when jquery is enabled? Any chance of a plunker that shows it?